# Apache mod_jk load balancing issue

Tags: apache, load-balancing, tomcat8, mod-jk

I've two applications (**app1** and **app2**) was deployed on two tomcats (**tomcat1** and **tomcat2**), other application (**sso**) was deployed on other tomcat (**tomcat3**) and I've installed apache web server with **mod_jk** with the following configurations but getting 404 error for **sso** when redirecting from **app1** to **sso**. For two applications (**app1** and **app2**) there is no issue but for **sso** getting 404 error.

**workers.properties**

```
worker.list=balancer

#Define Node1
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.port=8008
worker.tomcat1.host=abc.com

#Define Node2
worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.port=9009
worker.tomcat2.host=abc.com

#Define Node3
worker.tomcat3.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat3.port=8009
worker.tomcat3.host=abc.com

#Load-balancing behaviour
worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2,tomcat3
```

**httpd.cnf:**

```
JkMount /app* balancer
JkMount /sso* balancer
```

And in each tomcat server.xml contains below tag with different ports

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

> Apache: 2.4.41 Tomcat: 8.0 mod_jk: 1.2.46 JDK 1.8

It's my local setup. Am I missing any thing. I'm new to tomcat clustering any one please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three Tomcat servers cannot act as a cluster apiece, as there are two apps (app1 & app2) running in two tomcat (tomcat1 & tomcat2) and ther third one sso running in tomcat3.

What is happening here using your workers.properties when redirecting from app1 to even app2 or sso is that `mod_jk` is redirecting the request to the tomcat where you had been redirected before, due to session stickyness. So that it works like a charm when been redirecting from app1 to app2, as both apps are deployed to tomcat1 and tomcat2, but you receive a HTTP 404 when being redirected to sso, as your jsessionid cookie is bind to tomcat1 or tomcat2 making it redirect the sso request to the same tomcat, and receiving a 404 just because sso is not deployed there.

With that deployment plan, you should configure a balancer just for tomcat1 and tomcat2 and leave tomcat3 out of the balancer, acting as a standalone tomcat. This could be done this way:

```
worker.list=balancer,tomcat3

#Define Node1
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.port=8008
worker.tomcat1.host=abc.com

#Define Node2
worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.port=9009
worker.tomcat2.host=abc.com

#Define Node3
worker.tomcat3.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat3.port=8009
worker.tomcat3.host=abc.com

#Load-balancing behaviour
worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2
```

This way all should work, getting rid of HTTP 404 errors